# Package not available for this type of computer

Tags: packaging, deb

I am creating a deb package for an opensource project I have started called
[WideMargin](https://bitbucket.org/trampster/widemargin/wiki/Home)

When I try and install my deb package in 10.10 using the Ubuntu Software Center I get the following text on screen.

> Sorry, 'widemargin' is not available
>   for this type of computer (i386).

Despite this message it still installs and works fine.

In my control file I have the following line:

```
Architecture: all
```

I assumed this would allow it to work on all architectures.

What am I doing wrong?

As this is an open source project please feel free to poke around in my package source and tell me whats wrong.

I ran the following command as requested:

> dpkg-deb --control widemargin_1.0.0_all.deb

And it produced the following results:

```
Package: widemargin
Version: 1.0.0
Architecture: all
Maintainer: Daniel Hughes <trampster@gmail.com>
Installed-Size: 4744
Depends: mono-runtime (>= 2.6.7), libgtk2.0-cil (>= 2.12.10), libmono-sqlite2.0-cil (>= 2.6.7)
Section: unknown
Priority: extra
Homepage: https://bitbucket.org/trampster/widemargin
Description: Quick and simple bible software.
 Bible software with a focus on speed and usability.
```

Comment: Software Center is nowadays very picky. Try installing with dpgk.

Comment: there is no message with dpgk

Comment: @Takkat I am expecting my users to use the software center, So I need to fix the package, not find a work around for installing

Comment: Can you add the output of `dpkg-deb --control your_package.deb` to your question?

Comment: afaik the Software Center checks with lintian.

Comment: @lekensteyn that command produces no output....

Comment: @trampster: I forgot to mention that you've look at the newly created `DEBIAN/control` file.

Comment: I built the code on 10.10, 11.04, and the dev version of 11.10 and was unable to reproduce any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this problem by...

Rebooting!

And it magically started working. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

My computer is an i386 which is what most computers are.  I'm not sure of all the options here, but on my computer the line:

Architecture: all

Should be changed to:

Architecture: i386

Comment: The program is written in c# and uses mono, it is architecture independent. So it will work on all architectures. As such it does not need to be built for each architecture.